# Create a Pagination navigation bar in IOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to create a navigation bar for loading 10 items at a time inside my UITableView. The image of the navigation bar is given below.

[image]

How can I do this? I searched for controls in cocoacontrols.com but didn't find anything similar to the one I am trying to implement.

Comment: You can simply make a custom UIView and add buttons to it.

Comment: You should post what code you have already tried, as-is this question is too broad.

Comment: Try to build a custom UIView (Your own component) and use it. Remove the question and try build it yourself and comeback here ask for help when you stuck.